# Are hover in CSS and visibility in JavaScript not compatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

So, I have an icon. When I hover over the icon, a tooltip is display if I hover over the icon.

The HTMl is:

```
     <i class="fa fa-info-circle infoIcon">
       <span class="tooltip">
         <span class="tooltipClose">x</span><br>
         <p>some text</p>
      </span>
```

And the CSS is

```
   .infoIcon:hover {
     .tooltip {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
     }
   }
```

Now, if I hover over the icon labelled with class "**infoIcon**", the tooltip will be displayed. If I hover out the icon, the tooltip with be gone. However, there a is close button on tooltip labelled with class, "**tooltip**". If I click on it, the tooltip needs to be gone.

To do so, I used jQuery:

```
    $(".tooltipClose").click(function (e) {
        $(this).closest(".tooltip").css("visibility", "hidden");
      });
```

The tooltip will be gone if I click on the close button. However the problem is, the tooltip will not displayed again if I hover over the icon again. I know it is because I set the visibility of the tooltip to hidden in jQuery. How can I accommodate this issue so that I can close the tooltip when I click on the button and hover out the icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen for the `mouseleave` event and set the css back to nothing, as an inline style will take precedence over the stylesheet, so you need to set the property back to what it should be:

```
$(".tooltipClose").click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest(".tooltip").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(this).closest(".tooltip").one("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).css("visibility", "");
    });
});
```

Comment: But once you move you mouse away from the close button, the tooltip is displayed again.

Comment: Can you explain why setting visibility to "" actually works?

Comment: It removes the inline style, so then it will fallback to the stylesheet

Comment: Ok, I see. So in my original question, the hover doesn't work after clicking the close button is because the click event set the visibility to hidden as an inline style, in which overrides the hover on CSS. Am i right?

Comment: Exactly, if you look at the dom after clicking, you would see `<span class="tooltip" style="visibility: hidden">`, which overrides the CSS.  By setting it to `""`, it turns back into  `<span class="tooltip">`

Comment: But how come when I set visibility to visible in jQuery and turn it into "<span class="tooltip" style="visibility: visible">", it does not override anything including hover out.

Answer (score 1):

If the `tooltip` is the bootstrap one, the JQuery should have the support for the tooltip functionalities, and so to close one of those you should do something like:

```
$(this).closest(".tooltip").tooltip("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery method you are using `.css()` applies styling to tag itself as attribute.
So the attribute/inline styling takes first preference rather your hover style from external / internal stylesheet.

So what you should do is toggle a class or a property for the tooltip.

```
Tooltip -> meant for show on hover and hide on mouseleave.
Popover -> meant for staying and act on close button click.
```

But if you want `close button` click as an option then mouseleave isn't best solution.

```js
$(".tooltip").parent().on('mouseover', function() {
  $(".tooltip").hide();
  $(this).find('.tooltip').show();
})
$(".tooltip").find('.tooltipClose').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

```css
.infoIcon, .text {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  display: none;
  background: #22222240;
  width: 200px;
}
.tooltipClose {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="fa fa-info-circle infoIcon">
   <span class="tooltip">
      <span class="tooltipClose">x</span><br>
      <p>some text</p>
   </span>
</i>
<div class="text">
  Another Text (i)
  <span class="tooltip">
     <span class="tooltipClose">x</span><br>
  <p>some tooltip</p>
  </span>
</div>
```